# How to add Cassandra MaxRequestsPerConnection using properties file in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Spring boot project, in which I use Cassandra as a database.

Currently, I am getting Cassandra instance by auto-wiring `CassandraOperations`.

**My question is**:

How can we set `MaxRequestsPerConnection` using a property file?

```
# spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=event
# spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
# spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

Currently, I have these properties on my property file, but I didn't found any property for  setting `MaxRequestsPerConnection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot does not offer a configuration of all properties. You can define a `ClusterBuilderCustomizer` bean to customize `Cluster` instances.

Try the following code to declare a customizer bean which gets properties injected that can be provided via a properties file (more generally speaking, any property source available to Spring Boot):

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ClusterBuilderCustomizer clusterBuilderCustomizer(
            @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pool.max-requests-local:10}") int local,
            @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pool.max-requests-remote:5}") int remote) {

        PoolingOptions options = new PoolingOptions();

        options.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, local);
        options.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, remote);

        return builder -> builder.withPoolingOptions(options);
    }
}
```

An alternative to `@Value` is using a configuration class (annotated with [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) which gives you IDE support (such as property-name auto-completion).

Comment: I stumbled upon this question now asking myself what is happening in the return statement. I see that ClusterBuilderCustomizer is a FunctionalInterface having a single method that takes a com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Builder as input. I have no clue where the "builder" comes in the return statement and what the lambda does, the only idea I have is that it has to do with the method return type...

Comment: I am trying to figure that out as well. Anyone know how or where this comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Step No : 1
In application.properties file we have to declare local and remote pool size (required size value )

```
# spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=event
# spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
# spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
# spring.data.cassandra.pool.max-requests-local:20
# spring.data.cassandra.pool.max-requests-remote:10
```

Step No:2

in the Bean Configuration :

@Bean
ClusterBuilderCustomizer please get the values by using the following code (using @value annotation):

```
 @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pool.max-requests-local}")
  private int localPool;

  @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.pool.max-requests-remote}")
  private int remotePool;
```

By using this PoolingOptions class set the setMaxRequestsPerConnections  for local and remote

```
HostDistance.LOCAL -- localPool
HostDistance.REMOTE -- remotePool
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Spring Boot [2.3.0 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3.0-M1-Release-Notes), ClusterBuilderCustomizer has been replaced with DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer and CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer. As said in [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61345618/2599865), You just need to declare two beans having these types:

```
@Bean
public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer cqlSessionBuilderCustomizer() {
    return cqlSessionBuilder -> cqlSessionBuilder
            .withNodeStateListener(new MyNodeStateListener())
            .withSchemaChangeListener(new MySchemChangeListener());
}

@Bean
public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer driverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer() {
    return loaderBuilder -> loaderBuilder
            .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }
}
```