# Spring Boot 2.3.0.M4, Cassandra, and SSL

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have been using `ClusterBuilderCustomizer` to customize the SSL connection between my Spring Boot application (2.2.5.RELEASE) and the Cassandra database. After migrating to Spring Boot 2.3.0.M4, my code no longer compiles as the `ClusterBuilderCustomizer` doesn't exist anymore.

As per [Spring Boot 2.3.0 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3.0-M1-Release-Notes), it has been replaced with `DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer` and `CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer`. Does anyone have a working example on how to use any of these customizer classes with SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare two beans having these types:

```
@Bean
public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer cqlSessionBuilderCustomizer() {
    return cqlSessionBuilder -> cqlSessionBuilder
            .withNodeStateListener(new MyNodeStateListener())
            .withSchemaChangeListener(new MySchemChangeListener());
}

@Bean
public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer driverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer() {
    return loaderBuilder -> loaderBuilder
            .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }
}
```

Use `CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer` to pass runtime objects to the session builder, e.g. node state listeners or schema change listeners.

Use `DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer` to programmatically customize the driver configuration. See the [driver docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.5/manual/core/configuration/#programmatic-application-config) for more information on how to programmatically configure the driver.